# Installing spyder in python 3.5.0

Tags: python, spyder

Trying to install spyder using pip (python 3.5.0), the installation is completed but when I try to execute it. window just pops saying python stopped working

```
pip install spyder
spyder3
```

Any Ideas?

I am using windows 64x and I am installing it via pip and not anaconda.
I am also installing it in a virtual env folder.

Comment: you need to provide info of your machine: win, linux, mac ... also if you use anaconda or installed python standalone ...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issues, when installing spyder with pip. I could not quite figure out what exactly was causing the problem, but the quick fix for me was creating a new anaconda environment and installing spyder with conda install. Hope it helps

Comment: I need it to be outside anaconda

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) @MiguelSantos, pip installations are not supported by us precisely because of this kind of issues. If you are unable to pass this initial obstacle (which is a very simple one) you'd be much better by using Anaconda.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Hey, thank you for your answer, got it. By the way, great work with spyder, it is just an amazing IDE and I can't really live without it hehe : )

Comment: @MiguelSantos, no problem. Great to know that you enjoy using Spyder!

Answer (score 0):

I have Python 3.6 with spyder. I've installed python in standalone in the folder: `C:\Python36`. i.e. same as you.

Thus to start spyder, I created a shortcut towards: `C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py`.